# Read all files in folder tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tcltk

I want to read all files containing .sdc
The folder includes

```
alpha.sdc
beta.sdc
gamma.rpt
```

I try cmd

```
set a [open "proj/plrs/*.sdc" r]
```

but it not working

Comment: You'd have to loop the files. See glob: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.html

Comment: Or somehow join them. Perhaps by `exec cat ...`

Answer (score 2):

@Andreas has the right ideas.

```
set files [glob proj/plrs/*.sdc]
set combined ""
foreach file $files {
    set fh [open $file r]
    append combined [read $fh]
    close $fh
}
```

To use the glob characters with cat, you'll need a shell to interpret them:

```
set combined [exec sh -c {cat proj/plrs/*.sdc}]
```

or expand the results of `glob`

```
set combined [exec cat {*}[glob proj/plrs/*.sdc]]
```

You could use [tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/index.md)

```
package require fileutil
set combined [fileutil::cat {*}[glob proj/plrs/*.sdc]]
```

---

Note that `glob` doesn't sort the files like the shell does, so you may want

```
set files [lsort [glob $pattern]]
```